# Recoger parametros en sesion JEE

Tags: java, session

Tengo una pequeña aplicacion donde lo primero que aparece es un formulario de inicio de sesion. Donde si el usuario mete correctamente los datos accede a la pagina del menu donde puede guardar unos registros en la base de datos. El problema es que no estoy guardando bien la sesion o que estoy accediendo de una manera erronea ya que cuando trato de acceder me da un fallo (NullPointerException).

La sesion lo guardo mediante el servlet de inicio de sesion. Es decir, con los datos que mete el usuario los recojo con el request y llamo a un metodo que comprueba si el dato de usuario y contraseña estan en la base de datos. Si existe guarda la sesion y accede a menu.jsp. lo guardo de esta forma:

```
session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("user", user);
session.setAttribute("pass", pass);
session.setAttribute("obj", usuObj);
```

En ese momento el usuario esta en el menu y en toeria, la sesion esta creada. Entonces en la pagina de insertar un registro en la bd. Quiero acceder al objeto que he añadido a la sesion.

```
usuObj = (usuarioObj) getServletContext().getAttribute("obj");
id_usu = usuObj.getIdUsu();
```

Pero me da fallo en esa linea:

```
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[AddActividad]: Servlet.service() for servlet AddActividad threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at HorarioJ2EE.Control.AddActividad.processRequest(AddActividad.java:70)
at HorarioJ2EE.Control.AddActividad.doPost(AddActividad.java:122)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Entonces no se si el fallo esta en que no guardo la sesion bien, o si la sesion la creo pero en cuanto salgo del servlet y me redirijo al menu la sesion desaparece o si no estoy accediendo como es debido.

Por ultimo, en el servlet donde tengo el problema tengo esta linea de codigo:

```
session = request.getSession(true);
```

Comment: estás inicializando el `request`? o el `usuObj `?

Comment: el usuObj si pero el request no

Comment: HttpSession session  session = request.getSession(true); ¿Esto no, no?

Comment: session session? Se te ha duplicado el nombre de variable al copiar o lo tienes así?

Comment: se duplico. Al principio del codigo tengo: HttpSession session. Y mas abajo lo uso : session = request.getSession(true);

Answer (score 2):

```
usuObj = (usuarioObj) getServletContext().getAttribute("obj");
```

El `ServletContext` no es lo mismo que el `Session`... De hecho, el `ServletContext` es común para toda la webapp

```
usuObj = (usuarioObj) request.getSession(true).getAttribute("obj");
```

**UPDATE** Perdón por el retraso, pero lo que me cuentas no me cuadra, así que aquí va un plan para repasar posibilidades:

1. No lo dije en el comentario, pero el `System.out.println(request.getSession(false))` deberías hacerlo **antes** de `usuObj = (usuarioObj) request.getSession(true).getAttribute("obj");`.

   La diferencia es que si lo haces después, al hacer `request.getSession(true)` creas la sesión si ésta no existía antes; la idea del `System.out.println` es ver si -por alguna razón- la sesión donde has guardado los atributos ha desaparecido.
2. Si el punto 1. no aclara nada, podría ser de utilidad asignar *listeners*:

   - [`HttpSessionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) para ver qué sesiones se crean y destruyen, y cuándo pasa eso. [Aquí hay un ejemplo de implementación](https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/).
   - [`HttpSessionAttributeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html) para ver qué valores se asignan y qué valores se borran de los atributos del `Session`. [Aquí hay un ejemplo de implementación](https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionattributelistener-example/).

Por último, recordar que si lo solucionas la cuestión por tu cuenta, está permitido (y se agradece) que escribas y aceptes tu propia respuesta para que pueda ayudar a otras personas que tengan el mismo problema.

Comment: Por supuesto, es conveniente que si hay algún problema (sesión no inicializada al llamar al método, por ejemplo) se trate de forma *amigable*; por ejemplo, poner un filtro http que compruebe al inicio de cada petición que el atributo `obj` existe y que, en caso contrario, redireccione a la página de login.

Comment: sigue dando el mismo error. gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Comprueba si `request.getSession(false)` te devuelve un objeto o `null`.

Comment: He echo esto para ver lo que me devuelve en la consola de GlashFish: System.out.println(request.getSession(false)); Y me devuelve esto en la consola: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@645c4a4d. Parece que si me esta devolviendo una sesion. He intentado acceder no solo al objeto que guarda sino  todo lo demas y no puedo